# Getting the html base document using shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to get HTML base documents in VSCode using shortcut, like Sublime Text 3 that by just using HTML + TAB generate an HTML base document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know Sublime, but I guess you want:

- Open an empty html document (empty index.html for example)
- Write "doc"
- Press TAB

[image: Init html base document]

Comment: vscode calls those "Emmet Abbreviations".  "html" for instance will get you a quick panel with three suggestions.  Arrow down to see a preview of each.  "html5" also gives you what you want.  So in general you can use this method for many Emmet completions, like "div.myClass".

Comment: Thanks for the solution and I've got new idea about the so called Emmet Abbrevations. Some cheatsheet I've got are here https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/